# Which Widget and/or Navigationpattern for Day View of Calories-Tracker App

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

My problem is about a calorie counter I'm creating which has a navigation drawer with fragments for the side tabs which are already implemented. My home page is a fragment which displays a ListView of the calories the user inputs.

**Is it possible when the user slides to the left of the screen it goes to the next day where they can see the calories they consumed that day like the home page fragment?**

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Would I need to create another fragment or can I still use my homepage fragment "where displays that day of calories "how would I do it,implement that on my app